# builder.parse() with bindingContext

Tags: nativescript, angular-nativescript

I have the following code:

```
  private loadSlides(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const component = builder.parse(slideTemplate);
      component.bindingContext = {
        content: 'HHAHAAHA'
      };
      resolve(component);
    });
  }
```

and this is the value for slideTemplate:

```
export const slideTemplate: string = `
  <GridLayout row="0" rows="*, 2*, *">
      <GridLayout width="57%" row="0" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
          <Label class="lobster-regular carousel-item-head" [text]="content" textWrap="true"></Label>
      </GridLayout>
  </GridLayout>
`;
```

Now when I bind the value from my template it only shows empty string.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Angular template / binding syntax with `builder.parse(...)`, it's created outside Angular context.

Since you are using `bindingContext` which is NativeScript Core way of handling data binding, you should use `text="{{ content }}"`

```
export const slideTemplate: string = `
  <GridLayout row="0" rows="*, 2*, *">
      <GridLayout width="57%" row="0" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
          <Label class="lobster-regular carousel-item-head" text="{{ content }}" textWrap="true"></Label>
      </GridLayout>
  </GridLayout>
`;
```

I'm unsure why you may need builder here, I would suggest sticking with Angular components if possible.